# Finding the local extrema of $f(x, y) = \sin(x) + \sin(y) + \sin(x+y)$ on the domain $(0, 2 \pi) \times (0, 2 \pi)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

I am trying to find the relative extrema of
$$f(x, y) = \sin(x) + \sin(y) + \sin(x+y), \text{  where  } (x, y) \in (0, 2 \pi) \times (0, 2 \pi)$$

Setting the partial derivatives equal to zero gives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) = \cos(x) + \cos(x+ y) = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) = \cos(y) + \cos(x+ y) = 0$$

Subtracting the equations gives $\cos(x) = \cos (y)$, and since $0 < x, y < 2 \pi,$ we can see from the unit circle that this equation holds $\iff y = 2\pi - x \iff x+y = 2\pi$. Now using this information in the two equations above, we get

$$\cos(x) + \cos(2 \pi) = 0 \implies x = \pi$$
$$\cos(y) + \cos(2 \pi) = 0 \implies y = \pi$$

However, I graphed $f$, and this seems incorrect. In the pictures, we can see that there appears to be a local maximum around $(1, 1)$ and around $(5.5, 5.5)$. Could someone please tell me my mistake? [image]

[image]

Comment: With which program did you plot those graphs?

Comment: @PtF I used https://www.math3d.org/

Comment: Nice, I'll check it out =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\cos(x) = \cos (y) \implies x=y \:\lor\: x=2\pi-y$$

it seems you only have considered the second condition.

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty funny.

Comment: @Blue Yes often we forget the other one! :)

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

The equation
$$\cos(x)=\cos(y)$$ has a solution, other than the one you gave,  which is simply $ x=y$.

after replacing this in the two equations, one gets
$$\cos(x)+\cos(2x)=0$$
or
$$2\cos^2(x)+\cos(x)-1=0$$
thus
$$\cos(x)=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{9}}{4}$$
$$=\frac 12 \text{ or } -1$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Altough you had the more complete one, I gave the checkmark to the first poster.